# Windows 10 headphone volume abnormally loud

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones, 3.5mm

Whenever I plug any headphones into the 3.5mm jack, I have to turn down the Windows volume to 2 for the sound to be bearable.

I also do not see a  'Headphones' when I click on the sound icon in the bottom-right corner, only 'Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)'.

These problems do not persist if I use Bluetooth. I saw many people online have the same problem, but I haven't found a solution.

I have checked for updates for the audio driver not there were none.

Computer: Acer Aspire S5 371T

Windows Version: 1809

Realtek Driver Version: 6.0.1.7773

Comment: In your sound settings under the "Enhancements" tab do you have the option "Loudness Equalization"? if this is not activated please try turning this on.

Comment: @CraftyB Hi there, after turning on Loudness Equalization, the volume at low settings did not change, and is still loud. Strangely enough, I had to to follow the following guide just to find the 'Enhancements' tab: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoYl8CLLQHo